# How to refresh the whole dictionary if some element has been changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

```
<body ng-controller="SomeListCtrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">
      {{bindUserToImg(user.id)}}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button ng-click="update()">Update img</button>
</body>

function SomeListCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
    {id: 3}
  ];

  $scope.images = {
    1: {src: 'img-1'},
    2: {src: 'img-2'},
    3: {src: 'img-3'}
  };

  $scope.bindUserToImg = function(x) {
    console.log(x);

    return $scope.images[x].src;    
  };

  $scope.update = function() {
    $scope.images[2].src = 'updated-img';    
  };
}
```

Code: http://jsbin.com/sanipiki/1/

I've bound users to images. Now if some image changes (call 'update' method to change image #2), angular will refresh all users (method 'bindUserToImg' will be called for the each element in the 'users' array). Is it possible to make angular to update only the specific image and prevent to refresh all dictionary elements?

Comment: What do you mean by "will refresh all users"? In your example, you only set the image on update, no other method is called.

Comment: try to press 'Update' button in the example (http://jsbin.com/sanipiki/1/) and see the log.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.
Simplified, when you make a change to a scope property, angular will trigger a digest cycle to see if any other properties on the scope have changed. There's currently no mechanism to restrict the digest cycle to a certain scope / component.

In your case angular it's additionally not possible for angular to "know" that only the binding for image number 2 changed. `bindUserToImg` could have any number of complex side-effects that change with its input (and be dependant on variables other than function arguments), so angular must execute it for all bindings.

The general rule is to minimize the complexity of scope bindings, since they execute so often. The first step is not to use functions, as they are more costly than simple object lookup. Your example can be easily simplified by using

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
  {{images[user.id].src}}
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it helps a little bit, but it still renders slowly. Do you know how to improve performance more? I do not know how to trace the angular actions, but it seems it does not update the single element in the dictionary only.

Comment: It renders slowly? Do you have a huge list?

Comment: The matter is each 'src' of 'images' stores base64 string of the image. I suspect the image rendering takes some time. As a result I need to prevent all collection refreshing when the single image changes.

Comment: It's not possible for me to say what exactly happens if you reproduction is simplified. In general, angular will not "refresh / rerender" anything that didn't change.